# How can I get a string that will only contain the last part of the POST response?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, kotlin

As a result of a POST request I get a response in the following form:

```
D/OkHttp: {"msg":"OK","uploadid":"1dd0ff732ca3b0fc3892180b3d67e0df","ids":["5e20fe2a688c775700049d4c"]}
```

How can I get a string that will only contain the last part of the response? Example: `string response = "5e20fe2a688c775700049d4c"`

Comment: The response is in JSON format, the easiest way will be to use a JSON parsing library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the GSON library, I got the Kotlin class from the JSON file and selected the null element.

```
 // Get Image response Id
    val gson = Gson()
    val imageResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body()?.string(), ImageResponse::class.java)
    imageMediaId  = imageResponse.ids[0]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25115695)

Comment: I am the author of the question and this is my solution, what do you not like?

Answer (score 0):

From http request you get the response which is what u got there. All you need now is to do this:

```
 //response is the string you got from server
 JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response);
 String s = jobject.getString("ids");

 TextView.setText("Response string is : " + s);
```

You could always check what the system reads using

```
 Log.i("TAG",response);
 //and for the element of json
 Log.i("Tag",s);
```

Comment: `ids` is an array of strings, not a string

Comment: yes my bad, didnt look :/ in this case it would return [string] he could use regex to delete those...

Comment: or use [getJSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/json/JSONObject#getjsonarray) method

Comment: The problem is that I don't get a response but I get override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>)

Comment: Are you using volley? https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

Answer (score 0):

```
        response.body?.string()?.let {
            val jsonObject = JSONObject(it)
            val ids = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ids")
            val id = ids.getString(0)
        }
```

`response.body?.string()` gets the json string you need. Then you can parse that string to get the desired value. The GSON library is more commonly used but you can also use the built-in `JSONObject` if you don't want to import GSON.